How to use the sorted() and min() function with OR-Tools in python?
I'm building a Python Sudoku Solver to solve the classic and non-classic sudokus using the cp_model from Google's ortools library. Specifically, I'm trying to write a method that solves a Sudoku Variant in which every row/column/subgrid contains 9 unique numbers between 0 - 11. For instance, if row 1 of the sudoku has numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], rows 2-9 cannot have the same numbers in any permutation. However, row 2 can have the numbers [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] since this is a distinct set of 9 numbers. Likewise, this distinction applies to all rows.
Here is the challenge: Since each row has 9 entries, for a given set of 9 numbers, there are 9! different permutations in a row for them to appear.
So, I decided to go with creating a Unique signature for each row. Get all the elements of a row, sort them out in ascending order, and create an 18-digit signature unique to a row. For example, for row 1 with elements [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], the unique signature would be 010203040506070809. So, if some other row has the same 9 numbers in some other permutation, it will also have the same signature of 010203040506070809. This signature will only be different if the row has another set of 9 numbers regardless of the 9! possible permutations. Hence if I add a constraint that all the unique signatures must be different, I should get what I want.
Unfortunately, this isn't working since the sorted() method or list sorting is not working well with ortools. So, I had to go for a crude approach and generate all the 9! signatures (I am aware that it is computationally expensive) and pick the smallest signature to be the Unique Signature using the code snippet below.
def DistinctRowColSubGridConstraints(self):
        '''
        Collect all rows, create a unique lexicographical signature for each row,
        and ensure that all rows are unique.
        '''
        
        # Helper to encode a row as a lexicographical signature based on permutation indices
        def encode_as_lexicographical_index(row):
            
            # Create a list of indices: [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1] where n is the row length
            n = len(row)
            indices = list(range(n))
            
            # Generate all permutations of the indices list
            all_permutations = list(permutations(indices))
            
            # Generate All Signatures
            All_Signatures = []
            for perm in all_permutations:
                signature = 0
                for idx in perm:
                    signature = signature * 100 + row[idx]  # Concatenate each element to form the signature
                All_Signatures.append(signature)
            
            return All_Signatures

        # Collect all rows and create lexicographical signature for each
        row_signatures = []
        for i in range(self.Rows):
            
            row = [self.Cells[i][j] for j in range(self.Cols)]  # Get the row
            all_signatures = encode_as_lexicographical_index(row)  # Get all possible signatures
            
            RowUniqueSingature = self.Model.NewIntVar(lb=10**17, ub=10**18-1, name=f"RowUniqueSignature_{i}")
            self.Model.Add(RowUniqueSingature==min(all_signatures))
            
            row_signatures.append(RowUniqueSingature)  # Add signature to list
        
        # Ensure all rows have unique lexicographical signatures
        self.model.AddAllDifferent(row_signatures)

        print("Distinct row constraints added.")

Unfortunately, this is also not working since min() cannot work on Bounded Linear Expressions.
I would appreciate any help or guidance on fixing this issue. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me to a much efficient solution. Thank you.

Is it the question that you have an input of distinct numbers between 0 and 10 and need to sort them? For example, if your input is 1, 5, 3, you want to output 010305? And you need to collect all such signatures with input being 9 distinct numbers from 0-10?

My question is to find an optimal way to enforce a constraint that all the rows have to be unique - meaning, no two rows should share the same set of 9 numbers in any permutation. I tried using sorted() method to bypass all permutations, but it is not working. That's why I tried a sub-optimal min() approach so that I can produce a unique signature for each row. And as you can see, even min() is throwing errors.

In CP-SAT the equivalent to min() is:
add_min_equality (self, LinearExprT target, Iterable[LinearExprT] exprs)
And sorted() can be formulated e.g. by iterating the positions and adding constraints like position[i] < position[i+1].
IIRC, there is actually a soduko solver in the samples section (on ortools’ GitHub).
Edit: (related to my comment below)
I found this link with basically the same topic as yours incl. the use of sorted() and min():    https://devcodef1.com/news/1446546/python-sudoku-solver-with-or-tools
But it looks strange to me calling the (stateless) CP-SAT solver incrementally that way.
Edit2: (with the understanding of the rules of the non-classic version from your comment)
Using ortools’ sudoku example as starting point, we can formulate the additional constraint you are looking for as add_all_different of all rows (and of all cols, and of all sub-grids/blocks) without calculating 9! permutations.

“extend” rows, cols, blocks by 3 additional positions to allocate all numbers from 0…11
“encode” these 3 positions’ numbers (sorted) with a 12-base to get a reference value for each row (col, block)
“ensure” the reference value of all rows are all_different (the same with all cols, and all blocks)

P.S. If my assumption here is right, there are only 12 different combinations to sum up to 45.
Output with the grid from your YT link as init:
(Colab via older iPad)
[  _   _   _ ][   5   4   _ ][   _   _   _ ] 
[  _   2   _ ][   _   6   _ ][   7   _   3 ] 
[  4   _   _ ][   _   0   _ ][   5   _   _ ] 

[  0   _   _ ][   _   _   _ ][  10  11   _ ] 
[  1   _   8 ][   _   _   _ ][   _   3   _ ] 
[  _   9   _ ][   _   _   _ ][   _   _   _ ] 

[  _   5   _ ][   _   2   _ ][   _   _   _ ] 
[  _   _   _ ][   9   8   _ ][   0   _   1 ] 
[  _   7  10 ][   _   _   _ ][   6   2   _ ] 

NumConflicts: 0
NumBranches: 0
WallTime: 0.058303263

[  9   0   6 ][   5   4   7 ][  11   1   2 ] 
[ 11   2   5 ][  10   6   1 ][   7   0   3 ] 
[  4   1   7 ][   3   0   9 ][   5   6  10 ] 

[  0   4   2 ][   8   1   3 ][  10  11   6 ] 
[  1  11   8 ][   7   9   0 ][   2   3   4 ] 
[  7   9   3 ][   2  10   5 ][   1   8   0 ] 

[  8   5   0 ][   1   2   6 ][   3   9  11 ] 
[  2   6   4 ][   9   8  10 ][   0   5   1 ] 
[  3   7  10 ][   0   5   4 ][   6   2   8 ] 

row: 0  encoded: 538
row: 1  encoded: 681
row: 2  encoded: 395
row: 3  encoded: 813
row: 4  encoded: 802
row: 5  encoded: 659
row: 6  encoded: 670
row: 7  encoded: 527
row: 8  encoded: 263

col: 0  encoded: 802
col: 1  encoded: 538
col: 2  encoded: 263
col: 3  encoded: 659
col: 4  encoded: 527
col: 5  encoded: 395
col: 6  encoded: 681
col: 7  encoded: 670
col: 8  encoded: 813

block: 0_0  encoded: 538
block: 0_1  encoded: 395
block: 0_2  encoded: 681
block: 1_0  encoded: 802
block: 1_1  encoded: 659
block: 1_2  encoded: 813
block: 2_0  encoded: 263
block: 2_1  encoded: 527
block: 2_2  encoded: 670


@Arun: Could you explain the difference between the classic and non-classic version? Or why you and the linked solution refer to sorted() and min() for that matter? Maybe I misunderstood: the way it is used in the linked solution is to add the numbers as constraints and calling the solver ‘gradually’? Why not add all given numbers as constraints at once and then call the solver?

Sure. In a classic sudoku, you fill each row, column, and 3x3 subgrid with numbers 1-9. What I'm dealing with here is a non-classic sudoku in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tYM2ClmjVo . You have to fill each row, column, and subgrid with 9 numbers between 0 - 11 such that they add up to 45. The numbers add up to 45 condition, and numbers being non-repeating are easier goals that I've incorporated separately in a different method. What I'm struggling with is putting constraints to enforce that each row will contain a different set of 9 numbers.

My spontaneous reaction to your explanation was to introduce auxiliary binary vars to compare the rows. After some thoughts, it can be done modifying ortools’ sample code with additional add_all_different()

Thank you, Anonymous. You've given me a good idea to work with that bypasses the permutation problem I've been facing. Initially, I didn't get it, but I got it after passively ruminating about your idea for a few hours. It will work if I create a few more variables, apply the sort condition, and carefully merge them with the rows/cols/grids to take advantage of the AddAllDifferent condition.

Glad it worked out and thanks for accepting my answer!  (Yes, if we used the ‘original’ 9 positions to do the ‘sorting’ it would be more complex as we have to keep one ‘copy’ in the original order as well.) Cheers!
